# Why does yslow identifiy my images, scripts and css as cookies?

Tags: html, performance, cookies, yslow

[image: Yslow]

I am using yslow version 3.1.4

Comment: Could i please get an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: maybe you got downvoted because you used a screenshot rather than plain text to explain the problem, you should've copied and pasted the text only for better SEO indexation and screen readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie is sent with every request made to the host domain that matches the `domain` and `path` attributes that were specified when it was set with a `set-cookie:` response header.

When your browser issues a `GET` for `print.css` its request header will still contain a `cookie:` header if the domain & path match.

To prevent this see [setting the path on cookie prevent it being sent in http static requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787710/setting-the-path-on-cookie-prevent-it-being-sent-in-http-static-requests).

Comment: Hi Alex. So basically my best option would be to load all my static content from a cdn? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: A subdomain is easier. Does it really matter? the "cost" of sending a cookie is tiny.

Comment: well the site is loaded with a lot of images so it would be nice.

Comment: I would just serve static content from a subdomain then.